# What are hostnames acutally used for?

Tags: hostname, mdns

Is there any other use besides mDNS for computer hostnames?

I could not really find a good explanation online.

Answer (score 0):

Adding hostname allows you to resolve your system's name for registers, localnets and internet. sing hostname in the /etc/hosts file you comunicate the localname to your kernel, you can check it using: cat /proc/sys/kernel/hostname.
The file /etc/nsswitch allows you to resolve the name in an order in case the first options can not resolve. For that, nsswitch uses the line host: which uses file(/etc/host), mdns, dns(/etc/resolv.conf) to search for the hostname.

Also the hostname stament in DHCP service allows you to give specific configurations and a 'hostname' for a local host.